# Playing music with Python while having an active and interactable GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, wave

I am testing how to play background music with Python for a school project. I made a clone of the game "simon" and have been trying to add background music to it as testing for when I put the music in my actual project. I have tried this in several ways, but the only one that allowed me to play any music was by using code I found on another site:

```
#!usr/bin/env python  
#coding=utf-8  

import pyaudio  
import wave  

#define stream chunk   
chunk = 1024  

#open a wav format music  
f = wave.open("F:\Python\pythont-testing\SIMON\Heavy Metal Psycho Nu Metal.wav")  
#instantiate PyAudio  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
#open stream  H
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  channels = f.getnchannels(),  rate = f.getframerate(),  output = True)  
#read data  
data = f.readframes(chunk)  

#paly stream  
while data != '':  
    stream.write(data)  
data = f.readframes(chunk)  

#close PyAudio  
p.terminate()
```

When I added this to the code for the clone I made, the GUI would stop responding. I used a sound editor to cut the code down from its full time to 10 seconds to test whether this fixed itself once the song finished. As it turns out, once the song has finished, the GUI starts responding again, but all of the buttons on the GUI do not function.

How I inserted this code (I assumed that since I was using a function, this would not mess with the "root.mainloop" which runs the GUI.

```
def play_music():
    #define stream chunk   
    chunk = 1024  

    #open a wav format music  
    f = wave.open("F:\Python\pythont-testing\SIMON\Heavy Metal.wav")  
    #instantiate PyAudio  
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
    #open stream  
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),  channels = f.getnchannels(),  rate = f.getframerate(),  output = True)  
    #read data  
    data = f.readframes(chunk)  

    #play stream  
    while data != '':  
        stream.write(data)  
    data = f.readframes(chunk)  


    #close PyAudio  
    p.terminate()  

play_music()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should probably be using [callback mode](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o) instead of blocking mode for your audio playing. That way you can have it running in the background while your program continues. (Also, it's just "Python")

Comment: Could You please clarify on that @Kupialos